# Not able to use package created with webpack locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

i have created demo_package with webpack but not able to use in on another package
following is the src/index.js,package.json and webpack.config.js file for demo_package

src/index.js

```
 function hello(){
  console.log("hellow world")
 }
export default hello;
```

demo/package/package.json

```
{
 "name": "demo_pack",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "dist/main.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "build": "webpack"
  },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "webpack": "^4.41.2"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
 }
}
```

demo/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
 module.exports = {
 entry: './src/index.js',
 output: {
   filename: 'main.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   },
 };
```

following is how I am using it in test

```
var hello =require('demo_pack');
 hello();
```

and the error is hello is not a function,
I have linked my package locally, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `webpack.config.js`.

```
const path = require('path');
 module.exports = {
 entry: './src/index.js',
 output: {
   filename: 'main.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   publicPath: "",
   library:"Hello",
   libraryTarget:"umd",
   globalObject: "this"
   },
 };
```

Comment: i have done it but its showing error like :ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Updated. So you could try again.